# How to enable ios location services in react native?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I am working on react-native mobile app both ios and android. In my app, i need to use GPS location services. if location services turn off I need to automatically navigate app screen to platform location settings page. I can able to achieve this in android using NativeModules. Now I need to do this on ios also.

Android :

```
NativeModules.OpenSettings.openNetworkSettings(data => {
  this.setState({
    locationEnabled : false
  })
});
```

I need help, to enable location services in ios.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i found a temporary solution to this issue.

```
Linking.openURL('app-settings:');
```

Comment: This opens my app's settings. This doesn't open "Location Services" like this does on iOS 10 - https://stackoverflow.com/q/52301580/1828637 - do you know a solution for this on iOS 11?