# how to programmatically open Settings > Privacy > Location Services in iOS 11+?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios11

If locationServicesEnabled return false, I'm prompting the user to enable their Location Services. The following URL works for 10.0+, redirecting the user to the Settings app and directly to the Location Services screen:

URL(string: "App-Prefs:root=Privacy&path=LOCATION")

However this doesn't work in iOS 11. It opens the Settings app, but doesn't drill down to the Location Services. Anyone knows what's the new URL for iOS 11+?

Answer (score 5):

Apple published a list of URLs which they explicitly allow at [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899).  Unfortunately if you use other URLs (such as the one you are trying to use) this can get your app rejected from the App Store.

Short answer: You cannot do what you are trying to do without breaking the App Store rules.

Answer (score 3):

In iOS 15 this wasn't working for me, as it was just opening the general settings page, but based on [shivi_shub](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52301919/3708095) answer and his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52301580/how-to-programmatically-open-settings-privacy-location-services-in-ios-11#comment91552438_52301919) I tried the following:

```swift
if let bundleId = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier,
   let url = URL(string: "\(UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)&path=LOCATION_SERVICES/\(bundleId)")
{
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

And it brought me to the location settings, which at least is a couple steps closer to the settings page I really want to show.

So I guess we could just do:

```swift
if let url = URL(string: "\(UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)&path=LOCATION_SERVICES") {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

Comment: `LOCATION_SERVICES` not working in iOS 16

Answer (score 2):

Use this-

```
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)
```

Using App-prefs may lead to the rejection of the app on app store.

Or you can try this also-

```
if let bundleId = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier,
let url = URL(string: "\(UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)&path=LOCATION/\(bundleId)") {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

Comment: but i want to open the general settings tab of the location (where it is deactivated), not the settings tab of my app :(

Comment: Try to change the url as --  URL(string: "App-prefs:root=LOCATION_SERVICES")

Comment: no not work under ios 11 :( did you make it working ?

Comment: `if let url = URL(string:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) { UIApplication.shared.open(url) }`

Comment: The solution proposed by SwiftArchitect works partially - it successfully opens the system Settings App, but the OP question was specifically how to open a subsection of Settings, i.e., Location, General, or Privacy.  The previous url extensions, like "root=General" do not work in iOS 12